# Insert into table1 from table2 based on conditions from table3

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello i have some problem with this:

I have 3 tables

Table **users**:

| username | tele | notify |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 555-123456 | true |
| user2 | 555-000123 | false |
| user3 | null | false |

Table **datesTimes**

| date | userame |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-10 | user1 |
| 2021-10-10 | user2 |
| ... | ... |

Table **out_notifications**

| telephone | message |
| --- | --- |

Now what i want insert data into table out_notifications from table datesTimes only for users which have telephone number and notification turned on.

So i have constructed following query:

```
INSERT INTO out_notifications (telephone,message)
SELECT (select tele from users where users.username = datesTimes.username),
       'some message'    --(generated by system)
FROM datesTimes
WHERE date = '2021-10-10';
```

Now where place a subquery which select only users with tel. number and notifications turned on ?

Used db PostgreSQL

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sounds like you want to do a simple INNER JOIN. in postgres that would look like: 'INNER JOIN users ON users.username = datetimes.username'. After that you could add a WHERE users.notify = 'true'. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a join instead of a subselect.

```
INSERT INTO out_notifications (telephone,message)
  SELECT users.tele,
     'some message'    --(generated by system)
  FROM users 
  JOIN datesTimes
      ON users.username = datesTimes.username,
  WHERE datesTimes.date = '2021-10-10'
    AND users.tele <> ''
    AND users.notify;
```

Comment: I assumed it wouldn't work without the join, Thank you very much.